# travis ci rails build error when installing momentJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, travis-ci

I'm trying to incorporate travis ci in my project, the travis console output shows

```
An error occurred while installing momentjs-rails (2.11.0), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install momentjs-rails -v '2.11.0'` succeeds before
bundling.
```

even though in my .travis.yml I have

```
language: ruby
rvm:
  - 2.2.1
before_install:
  - gem update --system
  - gem --version
  - gem install momentjs-rails -v '2.11.0'
```

when I check the before install for moment js, it does say that

```
Fetching: momentjs-rails-2.11.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed momentjs-rails-2.11.0
19 gems installed
```

so why is my build still getting the error with this gem?